# Managing linked content in marklogic

Tags: marklogic

Is there any way to link contents in marklogic so that when a particular version of the content is accessed then its corresponding linked contents are also retrieved?

Say there is a content named as country. There are two versions of the country, country_v.1 and country_v.2. There is a state named as stateA . stateA has three versions stateA_v.1, stateA_v.2 and stateA_v.3

First version of the country country_v.1 is linked to stateA_v.1
  Second version of the country country_v.2 is linked to stateA_v.3

So now when version 1 of country is accessed I need corresponding linked version of the state that is stateA_v.1
  Similarly when I request for country_v.2 then i need to get corresponding linked version that is stateA_v.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could obviously do this manually by maintaining the proper links.
But this may be one for you if you structure your documents right using XInclude
See the xinclude functions.

https://docs.marklogic.com/xinc

Comment: Thank you for the response. Went through Xinclude and it looks like better option. But I am also curious to know about the first option "You could obviously do this manually by maintaining the proper links." Could you please elaborate on the same.